# How do I calculate 'hits' here without the loop?

Tags: c, loops, modulo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ix;
    unsigned hits = 0;
    for (ix=0; ix < 128; ix++)
    {   
        if (ix % 4 == 0)
            continue;   

        hits++;
    }
    printf("%u hits\n", hits);
    return;
}
```

This isn't a programming question, I have no code like this. But I'm interested in the mathematical way to handle such a problem.
The printf returns "96 hits"
My question is, is there a formula for calculating 'hits' without the loop?

Comment: hits = 128 * 0.75

Comment: Or `hits = 128 * 3 / 4` if you don't want the overhead of floating point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece:

```
if (ix % 4 == 0)
    continue;
```

basically means "skip every fourth iteration". Which means that it's the same as reducing the mount of iterations with 25%. So in this case, since the operation `hits++` does not depend on the value if `ix` at all, the whole thing is the same as:

```
unsigned hits = 0;
for (ix=0; ix < 128 * 3/4; ix++)
{   
    hits++;
}
```

And since the only operation is an increment, you can change everything to just

```
hits = 128*3/4;
```